# Constexpr variable and division

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr

I'm trying to evaluate this simple expression at compile time using C++11 new constexpr feature:

```
template <int a, int b>
class Test
{
   static constexpr double c = a / b;
};
```

But here's what Clang keeps telling me:

```
Constexpr variable 'c' must be initialized by a constant expression
```

The weird thing is that the following compiles well:

```
template <int a, int b>
class Test
{
   static constexpr double c = a / 2.f;
};
```

Do you guys have any idea on why a/b is not a constant expression, and how could I evaluate this at compile time?

Using Clang compiler with -std=c++1y and -stdlib=libc++

**Update**

The following example causes the error with the original code:

```
Test<10,0> test1 ;
```

while:

```
Test<10,1> test1 ;
```

does not.

Comment: [Works with Clang 3.5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7e6dc72912ed4b5), and with my install of 3.7.

Comment: Unrelated but: You want to divide two integers and store the result as a double. The division result will be an integer, e.g. 1/2 is not 0.5 but 0. Is this really what you had in mind?

Comment: @usr1234567 you are right, I forgot the cast in the example.

Comment: I am retracting my close vote since the OP has clarified the source of the problem this is now reproducible.

Comment: @chris the OP clarified and it is now clear this failed due to undefined behavior.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, I really should have seen that coming, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why:

```
Test<10,0> test1 ;
```

fails is because you have [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to division by zero. This is covered in the draft C++ standard section `5.6` *[expr.mul]* which says:

> If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined

and [constant expressions specifically exclude undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21319413/1708801).  I am not sure what version of `clang` you are using but the versions I have available online do provide a divide by zero warning (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/b72iwZPheg7mxicv)*):

```
note: division by zero
static constexpr double c = a / b;
                              ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved. One of the template instance had `b=0`.
Somehow, Clang didn't warn me I was dividing by zero.
And `+Inf` is not a constant expression.