# Dividing by constant or by variable zero

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, nan

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double zero = 0;
    const double ZERO = 0.;
    std::cout << 0/zero << "\n"; // -nan
    std::cout << 0/0. << "\n";   // nan
    std::cout << 0/ZERO << "\n"; // nan
}
```

Why does `0/zero` produces `-nan`, why it differs from `0/0.` and what is the meaning of `-nan`?

Live demo [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vNQa5AMECkEZFrDh) for clang. [GCC gives](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hvQ9eHlB0cmuBOhj) `-nan` for all these cases. Trying to compile with MSVC [leads to complile error](http://rextester.com/PFHPT79409) for const values and `-nan` [for variable](http://rextester.com/KTNRQ31271).

Which compiler is the more correct by Standard in this case?

Comment: Division by zero is undefined. Anything and everything is both correct and not correct.

Comment: `nan` is `Not a Number`, it's used in floating point when there's no valid result possible.

Comment: Note if you had tried with constant expressions [it would have been ill-formed and required a diagnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29237475/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Is floating-point division by zero considered undefined even on implementations where `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559` reports IEC-compatible math, and would thus required to implement floating-point corner-case behaviors [including floating-point division by zero] in a manner consistent with that Standard?  [the linked page used *integer* division].

Comment: @supercat if it is undefined behavior then it is [ill-formed in a constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21319413/1708801) and requires a diagnostic. [T.C.'s comments help clarify this a bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276373/self-initialization-of-a-static-constexpr-variable-is-it-well-formed#comment56295043_34276373).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Floating-point division by zero would *generally* be Undefined Behavior, but if an implementation's `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559` reports IEC-compatible math, that would guarantee behavior in some cases where the Standard would *otherwise* impose no requirements.  If an implementation supports IEC-compatible math, the behavior of evaluating x/0.0 is defined as yielding one of three values based upon the value of x.

Comment: @supercat well, ubsan still trigger even if that is the case [see it live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/P0Ac4afyc70OenNa) ... so I don't think that is a correct interpretation ... maybe it is worth a bug report to clarify?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: A quality sanitizer should allow such behaviors to be configured.  The purpose of such programs is to detect constructs which may work on some machines, but not on *all machines of interest*.  If one will want to run code on some machines that support IEC559 and some that don't, one will want a sanitizer to squawk at things that would be UB on the machines that don't support IEC559, even if it's running on a machine that does.

Answer (score 2):

From the C++ Standard 5.6.4:

> If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined.

Division by `0` causes the dreaded undefined behaviour!  So the compiler is free to do anything included generating a `NaN`, writing code that crashes, and raiding your fridge.  There isn't a *more* correct behaviour.

For floating-point types, C++ has [`std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559) to test whether or not the implementation supports the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.com/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) standard for dealing with floating-points of type `T`.

Comment: If an implementation promises to use Annex-F-complaint math (common, though by no means universal), floating-point division by zero has behavior defined by that spec, and would thus not invoke UB.

Comment: @supercat Yes, but the OP asks about what is "more correct by [the] Standard". An implementation could also promise to raid your fridge :P

Comment: @PaulEvans: At least in C, if an implementation defines `__STDC_IEC_559__`, floating-point division by zero would not invoke UB on that implementation, since IEC559 defines the behavior and the C Standard would incorporate that by reference.  The C++ Standard incorporates much of the C Standard by reference, but I'm not familiar enough with the ins and outs to know if it excludes Annex F guarantees.

Comment: @supercat C++ has [std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559) to test whether or not the implementation supports IEC 559 for type `T`.

Comment: Division by 0 in floats is implementation defined.

Comment: @SergeyA Please see the C++ standard 5.6.4

Comment: @supercat -- regardless of what an implementation promises, the behavior of a program that divides by zero is undefined. That **only** means that the **standard** doesn't tell you what the program should do. Implementations are free to do whatever they like when a program has undefined behavior, including doing something perfectly sensible. They are not required to do nasty things.

Comment: @PaulEvans there is also 5.4, which somewhat legitimizes this (*and usually adjustable by library functions*).

Comment: @SergeyA section 5.4 in C++14 is [expr.cast] which has nothing to do with this topic

Comment: @M.M, http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf is where I am looking at, and it is not section [expr.cast], I used wrong numbering, should be 5/4. Begins with 'If during the evaluation of an expression...'

Comment: @SergeyA do you know why implementation choose `-nan` for this case instead of ordinary `nan`?

Comment: @alexolut, no, I do not see a reason for this. According to IEEE 754, this should produce NaN, since both operands are not negative.

Comment: @SergeyA you can find an answer on [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701038/176217).

Comment: @alexolut, yeah, found it independently. I am not sure the behavior is conforming, though.

Comment: @PeteBecker: In the C Stanard N1570, *An arithmetic constant expression of floating type, other than one in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration, is evaluated (as if) during execution; thus, it is affected by any operative floating-point control modes and raises floating-point exceptions as required by IEC 60559 (provided the state for the FENV_ACCESS pragma is ''on'').*.  C++ has additional cases where it evaluates things at compile time, like the right-hand side of `const` declarations, but certainly in C the behavior of the run-time `0.0/0.0` is defined...

Comment: ...by the Standard for implementations that support Annex F [above text is from F.8.4, btw].