# C++ template - evaluate static inline method inside template and pass result as template type argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template that accepts `class F` and `int X`. Class F has a `static inline double eval(double x)` method. Based on the result returned by `eval` I need to choose between `int` and `long` types - smallest possible that will fit the result (converted to a round number as it's double).

I tried doing it this way but I get `Non-type template argument is not a constant expression` error.

```
template <class F, int X>
struct DEDUCTOR {
   typedef SELECT<-32768 < F::eval(X) && F::eval(X) < 32767> result;    
}
```

where `SELECT` is defined this way:

```
template <bool is_int>
struct SELECT {};

template <>
struct SELECT<true> {
    typedef int type;
};

template <>
struct SELECT<false> {
    typedef long type;
};
```

Is there any way to create such template?

============================
UPDATE:

According to the advice, I added constexpr to the `eval` function. It works now, but now always. Full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <typeinfo>

struct X {
    static constexpr double eval(double x) { return x; };
};

template<class L, class R>
struct MULT {
    static constexpr double eval(double x) {
        return L::eval(x) * R::eval(x);
    }
};

template<class L, class R>
struct DIV {
    static constexpr double eval(double x) {
        return L::eval(x) / R::eval(x);
    }
};

template <bool is_int>
struct SELECT {
    typedef long type;
};

template <>
struct SELECT<true> {
    typedef int type;
};

template<class F, int X>
struct DEDUCTOR {
    typedef typename SELECT<-32768 < F::eval(X) && F::eval(X) < 32767>::type result;
};

int main() {
//    typedef MULT<MULT<X, X>, X> F; // works
    typedef DIV<DIV<X, X>, X> F; // doesn't work
    typedef DEDUCTOR<F, 0> deductor;

    std::cout << typeid(deductor::result).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not unless  `eval()` is a `constexpr` function that can be evaluated at compile time. Because that's when templates get instantiated.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I tried adding ‘constexpr’ in front of the function as it is compile time evaluated but it still displays same error.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: That means that the function is not a constant function, therefore it cannot be used in a template parameter. C++ simply doesn't work this way.

Comment: I try as `static constexpr double eval(double x) { return 0.0; }`, and i got no errors. Could you check this out? Or.. i guess your `eval()` function is not possible to calculate in compile time. In this case, `eval()` can't be `constexpr`.

Comment: I updated my answer to include full example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is this line:

```
typedef SELECT<-32768 < F::eval(X) && F::eval(X) < 32767> result;
```

it should be:

```
typedef typename SELECT < -32768 < F::eval(X) && F::eval(X) < 32767 > ::type result;
```

NOTE: trailing "::type" to actually refer to the type from your SELECT structs, and leading "typename" since it's a dependent type.

Below is a working version. Note that I slightly changed the SELECT as well, but this isn't required to compile.

```
template <bool is_int>
struct SELECT { 
    typedef long type;
};

template <>
struct SELECT<true> {
    typedef int type;
};

template <class F, int X>
struct DEDUCTOR {
    typedef typename SELECT < -32768 < F::eval(X) && F::eval(X) < 32767 > ::type result;
};

struct myS
{
    static constexpr double eval(double x) { return x; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(DEDUCTOR<myS, 100>::result).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(DEDUCTOR<myS, 100000>::result).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: you are dividing by zero after your update. change it to 1 and it works. [see here] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222319/constexpr-variable-and-division

Comment: Ah yes, I chose a wrong example :D Thank you anyway, I managed to figure out that the last issue was in the other implementation of eval() which used pow function. I needed to implement it myself. Thanks a lot, you helped me a lot!