# Floating point division by zero not constexpr

Tags: c++11, c++14, undefined-behavior, constexpr

When compiling this:

```
constexpr double x {123.0};
constexpr double y = x / 0.0;
std::cout << x << " / 0 = " << y << "\n";
```

The compiler (gcc 4.9.2, -std=c++11 or c++14) fails, giving error:

```
(1.23e+2 / 0.0)' is not a constant expression
  constexpr double y = x / 0.0;
```

How is the result (Inf) relevant when deciding if `y` can be a *constexpr* or not?

For reference, this seems to be the way to do it:

```
static constexpr double z = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
static constexpr double w = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Why do constant expressions have an exclusion for undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21319413)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Infinity is an implementation defined result, the standard does not require [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) and division by zero is formally [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and [constant expression have an exclusion for undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21319413/1708801).

From the draft C++ standard section `5.6` *[expr.mul]*:

> The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator
>   yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the
>   second. **If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is
>   undefined.**

Comment: `constexpr` is the magic undefined behaviour detector :-) Now we can finally do SFINAE on undefined behaviour.

Comment: @KerrekSB yeah, unfortunately, `gcc` accepts what is formally undefined behavior with shifts in constant expressions, which is kind of a fly in the ointment there. I have a bug report for it but no response yet.