# Does `is_iec559` imply anything concerning floating point arithmetic?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, standards

After going through various posts concerning this topic, it seems that things like floating point division by zero behavior isn't universally agreed upon when `is_iec559` is true, unlike an analogous situation in C, where there's Annex F which describes what floating point operations do. It's been many years since this was discussed, so I thought something might have changed, so I'm asking:

Assuming `is_iec559` is true in an implementation, are there any implications about about the basic `+-*/` operations when it comes to otherwise undefined behavior in the c++ standard, e.g. division by zero returning infinity? Or does `is_iec559` only guarantee the data storage format? Does it even guarantee anything?

More practically, are there any actual major implementations where this is not the case (i.e. `is_iec559` can be true, and yet `+-*/` do not conform to the IEC559 standard) under certain optimization flags etc.?

Comment: Division by zero behavior is universally agreed upon when `is_iec559` is true.  That universal agreement is called a *standard*.  I'm not sure what happens to the `is_iec559` check when the compiler is given flags that disable some-or-all of guaranteed behaviors.  I believe the switches involved caution that the flags should not be used if those behaviors should be in effect.  (e.g., if the doubles will **never** be NaN, disabling NaN behaviors is okay... until a NaN slips in, in which case we're not in Kansas anymore).

Comment: @Eljay It seems to be at least slightly contradictory to me that the standard describes something like division by zero to be UB conditionally for a float, and yet if `is_iec559` is true, float should conform to IEC559.

Relevant discussion can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926763/the-behaviour-of-floating-point-division-by-zero

Comment: Adrian Maire's answer to the question that you linked appears to answer your question.  The standard takes a loosey-goosey stance on floating point numbers because there are platforms that are not IEC 559 compliant.  The standard accommodates the needs of those non-IEC 559 platforms as well — which makes relying on portable floating point behavior tricky.

Comment: @Eljay Alright, thanks. Just to confirm - if `is_iec559` is true, this concerns everything about the floating type? Data layout, comparison operations, and all the basic (`+-*/` )operations? E.g. division of `1.0f/+0.0f` is guaranteed to be +infinity?

Comment: Also, here is another seemingly conflicting situation:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56097944/are-floating-point-operations-resulting-in-infinity-undefined-behavior-for-iec-5

It's in a constexpr context, but it's somewhat conflicting regardless.

Comment: For platforms that have IEC 559 hardware, the only non-compliance with any C++ that I am aware of is if the program opts-out of IEC 559 compliance (e.g., fast math flags).  I presume that such programs will still programmatically claim `is_iec559` compliance.