# Scoped enum with underlying type 'bool' truncates differently across compilers

Tags: c++, enums

I recently discovered that C++ Scoped enums are allowed to use `bool` as the underlying type, which somewhat makes sense since `std::is_integral_v<bool>` is `true`.

However, I've also found that the truncation behavior when `static_cast`ing to a type made this way causes different results across compilers. In particular:

```cpp
enum class Option : bool {
    No = false,
    Yes = true,
};

constexpr auto v = static_cast<Option>(8); 

std::cout << static_cast<bool>(v) << std::endl;
```

<kbd>[Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/q536sK14b)</kbd>

GCC reports this result as `false`, whereas Clang and MSVC report `true` (MSVC can be seen by checking the `mov     cl, 1` prior to calling).

This value reports as `true` for GCC if the last bit is set, so `static_cast<Option>(9)` will result in `true` as the underlying type:

```
constexpr auto v = static_cast<Option>(9); 

std::cout << static_cast<bool>(v) << std::endl;
```

<kbd>[Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WrEYeE4Ma)</kbd>

It seems that GCC treats the `static_cast` as a 1-bit unsigned integral value cast, and thus truncates the value to 1 bit, much like a `uint32_t` would narrow to a `uint8_t`, whereas Clang and MSVC both treat it like a normal boolean cast using `n > 0`.

**Which compiler here is correct?**
If this is some form of undefined behavior, why can it be used in a `constexpr` expression?

---

**Note:** An obvious workaround is to use `static_cast<Option>(static_cast<bool>(...))`, but I'm curious about what behavior should be expected here -- if any.
This behavior appears to be occur in all C++ versions that support scoped enums (from [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and up).

Comment: I'm not sure whether I should tag this as [tag:language-lawyer]... I kind of get the feeling this question might reach into that territory

Comment: If you do that (yes I think you perhaps shoule) I'll delete my answer ;-)

Comment: And @StoryTeller - Unslander Monica is listening in too and may submit an answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba actually looks like there is a reasonable duplicate for this already, so this question was closed. Seems that it's an unspecified value prior to CWG 1766, and undefined behavior after. Doesn't quite explain how this exists in constant expressions at all though.

Comment: @Human-Compiler Is *unspecified* behaviour the same as *undefined* behaviour?

Comment: That "duplicate" is about a different backing type. I'll reopen.

Comment: @Bathsheba That's your prerogative, of course, but I'm pretty sure the dupe I linked answers the question.

Comment: @AdrianMole: Linking to the C++ standard answers all questions too. Sometimes it's nice to have something a little more tailored.

Comment: Seems like it needs to follow the same path as a conversion to bool https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.static.cast#10.sentence-2

Comment: Some interesting stuff here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319413/why-do-constant-expressions-have-an-exclusion-for-undefined-behavior

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I'm confused how to apply this information. I agree that it appears like the cast to boolean should occur, but the previously-linked duplicate to this question seemed to suggest that the cast being out-of-range would be UB in the first-place.

Comment: @Bathsheba That might explain why it's accepted in `constexpr` when it shouldn't be. Very strange that it wouldn't catch this as being UB at compile-time though, when it would catch most other conversions

Comment: I think it's just a case of compiler versions. C++20 defines the code, and the fix is a DR, so it's retroactively well-defined too. Newer compiler versions should do as G++ and MSVC. Olders versions might not.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Do you mean Clang and MSVC (since they performed the conversion first)? If so, then it sounds like there may be a bug in GCC then, since compiling with `-std=c++20` still produces `false` rather than `true`. If you have a moment to type this up as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Yes, Clang and MSVC. I mistyped. I stand behind the dupe I chose though. It goes through the history of this from C++11 to C++20. Along with the biggest motivation (`std::byte` being well-defined).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I have no hard-feelings to this being re-closed as a dupe (I never did); though the answer to that question seemed to more indicate that it was UB rather than well-defined, as you're suggesting. Also I thought the motivation for `std::byte` being well-defined only applied to enums that had no enumerators explicitly defined (though my information might be outdated). **Edit:** Oh, I didn't realize the question was closed 10 minutes ago with a different dupe answer. Ignore me. Thanks!

Comment: Enumerators are just names for specific values of the underlying type (expressed as the enumeration type). I don't think defining the behavior really depends on the existence of enumerators.

Comment: Interesting note on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum): *Although the conversion from an out-of-range to an enumeration without fixed underlying type is made undefined behavior by CWG issue 1766, currently no compiler performs the required diagnostic for it in constant evaluation.*

Comment: I've edited the target list to include the original target that was used to close this question, as I think someone who has this question will find both those targets useful.